# Child routes depended on a condition in Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes

How I can load a component in a child routes depending on a condition?
My routes:

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
...
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
          if(isUser) { // <= this is an example that I want to do
           return {
             path: '',
             component: UserComponent, // if user is login in it should load this component
           }
          } else {
            return {
             path: '',
             component: NotUserComponent, // if no user it should load this component
           }
          }
        ],
      }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(mainRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

And the second question: It's possible to inject Authorization Service in router module and build routes depend on user login in?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a guard for that route as well, and you can inject the Auth Service in that guard.

> It's possible to inject Authorization Service in router module and build routes depend on user login in?

Yes, you can as you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295969/12327871), but I cannot recommend it.

Best regards